# Which "sigma" in CSS blur?

Tags: node.js, css, blur, graphicsmagick

I want to reproduce CSS blur with GraphicsMagic node.js lib, but CSS blur requires only radius and GM's blur requires radius and sigma. Which sigma value should i use?

Comment: CSS's `blur()`'s radius *is* the sigma value. "The value of ‘radius’ defines the value of the standard deviation to the Gaussian function". – [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter#blur()).

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Thank you, but CSS's `blur(5px)` and GM's `blur(0, 5)` looks different.